# How to get sum of values(recent) of user stored in different table

Tags: sql, plsql

i have a problem with an sql/pl sql query.

I have following 2 tables

table Profile(user, attribute, value)

e.g:

```
john, hobby, ‚this is a users hoppy‘
```

table Information(hobby, validFrom, price)
e.g:

```
Climbing, 01.09.2019, 3
Climbing, 01.01.2020, 4
```

I want to build a query which gets the value(sum of all prices) of a users profile of a user. Only the recent prices should be considered

I have tried many ways, but what i have achieved so far is only to get the most recent price of an attribute.
Can you please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question and show a table or the example data that is readable( try this - https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) , and the expected output, and what you have tried.  Also read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following correctly, you want to join the two tables but only on the most recent row:

```
select p.user, sum(h.price)
from profile p join
     (select h.*,
             row_number() over (partition by hobby order by validFrom desc) as seqnum
      from hobbies h
     ) h
     on p.attribute = 'hobby' and
        p.value = h.hobby and
        h.seqnum = 1
group by p.user
```